# Which is correct, would you or you would?

Tags: inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion

> What is one question **would you** like to ask a time traveler from 1000 years in the future?

or

> What is one question **you would** like to ask a time traveler from 1000 years in the future?

Comment: Is Trump still President?

Answer (score 2):

Both *would you* and *you would* can be grammatical, but only in different specific constructions.

Without *is*:

> ✔ What one question **would you** like to ask a time traveler from 1000 years in the future?
> ✘ What one question **you would** like to ask a time traveler from 1000 years in the future?

With *is*:

> ✘ What *is* one question **would you** like to ask a time traveler from 1000 years in the future?
> ✔ What *is* one question **you would** like to ask a time traveler from 1000 years in the future?